# endTime parameter doesn't works on Google Calendar 5.0 when using insert Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-calendar-api

Since Google updated the Calendar App to version 5.0 the extra data "endTime" `(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME)` sent on insert intent is ignored.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                Log.v("test", CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI.toString());
                intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,location);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, longMilisBeginTime);
                intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, longMilisEndTime);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Somebody can bring me some light about it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert, I still see the putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis()) in the document. Is this the same link you are referring to?

Comment: Yes. But in the new version of google calendar the insert event activity ignores endTime and populates the event endTime field with beginTime + 1hour always. Somebody knows if it is a bug or knows a workaround?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. My end time setting stopped working and all events are scheduled for one hour.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80266